# Gradle error when I wanna run the project on Emulator or Physical Device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

It was working just fine last night, today I can't run my Project, I get this `error`:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'. 
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Arash\.android\build-cache\...\output
```

tried **Invalidate and Clear Cache**, replace the project with the last version before Push and many other things

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it, in Project Level of **Gradle**

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

to:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

there's some issues with 3.1.1 i guess.

Answer (score 0):

1. try this I am also facing the same Problem.
2. In a terminal execute in the root folder

   ```
     ./gradlew clean
   ```

Comment: you mean put the cmd directory in the cache folder which input output file is and run this code? @Vishal Yadav

Comment: no, you've to open `terminal in Android Studio` and simply type this `./gradlew clean`

Comment: Close your Android studio and Restart your system and goto to the `path C:\Users\Arash\.android\build-cache`  `Delete it manually`

Comment: delete every file in this folder? it wont make new kinda error?

Comment: yes or locate the folder in which `error` is coming look `error`

Comment: fixed it, the problem was the version of gms-google-services in gradle @Vishal Yadav

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to clear the build cache:

On Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

On Mac or Linux:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Comment: done it, Failed with this error: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:cleanBuildCache'.
> java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Arash\.android\build-cache'.

Comment: Some of the files in the target build directory opened in another tool, please restart your PC and then after restart try to delete the directory or the file manually.